# Проверить существование тэга Schedule

Tags: python, schedule

Играюсь с многопотоками. Как проверить, существует ли определенный тэг у Schedule уже или еще нет?

Comment: Что это за Schedule? Я его даже по индексу найти не могу в документации (<https://docs.python.org/3.10/genindex-S.html>).

Comment: `Играюсь с многопотоками.` - schedule как-то немного ортогонально многопоточности. `Как проверить, существует ли определенный тэг у Schedule уже или еще нет?` - в такой постановке вопроса никак, тэги не существуют отдельно от джобов. Только запросить все джобы с указанным тегом (через [get_job](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#schedule.get_jobs)), если они есть, значит тег есть.

Comment: Ясно. Schedule - дополнительная библиотека.

Answer (score 0):

В общем придумал решение. Веселое, но все же может кому-то понадобится:

```
    for i in range(4):
    if len(schedule.get_jobs(str(i)))>0:
        continue
    else:
        schedule.every(2).seconds.do(go,message,str(i)).tag(str(i))
        break
```

Таким образом заполним тэги от 0 до 3